# WARNING: Using fallback font ArialMT for base font Symbol

Tags: fonts, pdf

**Version:**

- OS `lsb_release -a` : Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- PHP `php -v` : 8.0.1
- Apache `apache2 -v` : 2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
- Python3 `python3 --version` : Python 3.6.9

---

**Problem Statement:**

I'm using Python script which extract the text content from PDF file using [tabula](https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/) which is working fine in Local machine. However, In Remote Server Ubuntu I'm getting following **WARNING** as well script is not returning expected result because following **WARNING** message which I'm guessing this **WARNING** would be cause of not returning **NAME** from file.

---

**Exception:**

```
Got stderr: Apr 06, 2021 6:32:49 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Roman
Apr 06, 2021 6:32:49 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Bold
Apr 06, 2021 6:32:49 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Italic
```

---

**Tried:**

After installing [Windows fonts in Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/install-microsoft-fonts-ubuntu/).

Using Below command:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
$ sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

This is giving me following warning:

```
Got stderr: Apr 06, 2021 8:18:08 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font ArialMT for base font Symbol
Apr 06, 2021 8:18:08 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font ArialMT for base font ZapfDingbats
```

Comment: Do you have this font installed? PDType1Font

Comment: Yes, if a specified font is not present, it falls back to a similar present font. Can you elaborate on how that is a problem?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, I want to fix this warning message. As because of this I'm guessing that my script is not parsing the file. Which is working fine in my local where I'm not getting such error message.

Comment: @Maqsud: Then I suppose you need to install the Symbol and ZapfDingbats fonts somehow. AFAIK they are not installed via `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, Can you help me with command or article to install `Symbol` and ZapfDingbats`. I tried googling *install Symbol in ubuntu* and *install ZapfDingbats in ubuntu* but couldnt get anything.

Comment: @Maqsud: No, sorry, I don't know how to get those. You may want to submit a new question where you ask about that specifically.